# IMServicePlugIn for Jabber Server

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xmpp, osx-mountain-lion, ichat

I have to write a Messages plugin to access an internal Jabber server due to some special authentication.  I have two questions:

1. Is there source code available for the Messages Jabber plugin so I
   could just modify the authentication part and not have to write the
   whole plugin?
2. If not, how do I a send the status of each buddy  in the group list
   to the IMService?  I have created a plugin that can log in and
   retrieve the buddy list from the internal server. The buddy list is
   displayed in Messages with everybody offline, even the buddies who
   are on line.  I’ve spent days looking at the limited documentation
   and header s and I cannot figure out how to pass the status of each
   buddy in the group list to the IMService. When I get the group list)
   from the Jabber  server, I call the plugInDidUpdateGroupList method
   on my IMServiceApplication object.  I only see that I can pass the
   group name, permission, and name of each buddy.  They all show up
   off line.  How do I pass the status of each buddy?

Thanks.